# i have to make this function in my on my site like this (pls look my picture)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, events

actual(pcs/hr) = number of actual product/hour
actual(accum) = total number of product before + current actual(pcs/hr)
(with the **first actual(accum)** is number of (6h to 7h)) = actual(pcs/hr) of (6h to 7h).

I want when i change a actual(pcs/hr) value of the middle all of actual(accum) after that change too
[excel example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSb1v.png)

This is my code:

```
    var targetinputs = document.querySelectorAll(".input-target");
    var targetaccum = document.querySelectorAll(".target-accum");
    inputtargetArray.forEach(function (target) {
            target.addEventListener('focus', function (e) {
                var index = inputtargetArray.indexOf(e.target);
                //memoryfocus[index] = parseInt(e.target.value);
            }, true);
            target.addEventListener("change", function (e) {
                var index = inputtargetArray.indexOf(e.target);
                if (index == 0)
                    $('#Target-Accum-' + (index + 6)).val(targetinputs[index].value);
                else {
                    $('#Target-Accum-' + (index + 6)).val(parseInt(targetinputs[index].value) + parseInt($('#Target-Accum-' + (index + 6 - 1)).val())); 
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: Can you explain your question better? I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: it so hard to explain but thank u sir, i have done it use recursive. code :
function targetaccum(index) {
    var a = $('#Target-Accum-' + (index + 5)).val();
    var b = $('#Target-' + (index + 6)).val();
    var c = $('#Target-' + (index + 7)).val();
    console.log(c);
        if (c == "0")
            console.log("Ket thuc de quy");
            else {
               console.log("Gia tri moi = " + (parseInt(a) + parseInt(b)));
                $('#Target-Accum-' + (index + 6)).val(parseInt(a) + parseInt(b));
                targetaccum(index + 1);
                }
            }

Comment: I want you to go to [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/pen) and paste your HTML code into the HTML part of the code. Then, paste your CSS into the CSS part of the code. After that, paste your Javascript into the Javascript part of the code. Save your code and give me the link to codepen that you made.